# Zend Framework - how to tell nice looking url to go to static url?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have this following routing. How to tell `/nice-looking-url` to load  `/home/www/html/project/public/static/index.html` which is not in the Controller

```
$route = Http\Literal::factory(array(
  'route' => '/nice-looking-url',
  'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Nicelookingurl',
    'action' => 'index'
  ),
));
$router->addRoute('nicelookingurl', $route, null);
```

Comment: If it's a complete page, and static, and `*.html`, why not simply add a "serve as is" rule for `*.html` files in your Apache or nginx configuration, same as for `jpg|png|other` extensions?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do so is to add this line

```
return $this->renderScript('insert-your-script-path-here');
```

as first line in your Nicelookingurl index action

If you want to disable the layout you can also add

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```